# Count all letters on each line in a text file and print them out

Tags: c

I need to write a C script with which I should be able to count all letters on each line in a text file and print each value. The text file has to be a parameter given when running the C script.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    char *g, linie[1000];
    int nrChar=0;
    FILE *f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    g=fgets(linie,1000,f);
    while(g!=NULL)
    {
    nrChar=strlen(linie)-2;
    printf("cuv is %d\n",nrChar);
        g++;
        g=fgets(linie,1000,f);     
    }   

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

I am expecting something like:

```
2
3
5
4
1
```

Supposing I have a .txt file which contains:

```
do
abc
linux
bash
c
```

Comment: you are calling `strlen` to get the length of each line, but you aren't printing the value it returns

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings (`gcc ... -Wall -Wextra ...` / `clang ... -Weverything ...`) and **mind the warnings**.

Comment: ...and indent your code properly so you can see what's going on.

Comment: you don't need `fgets`, `fgetc` is enough. Probably easier too! Certainly more correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You aren't printing the value returned by `strlen` which is what you want to do.
2. `fgets` [leaves the trailing newline, if it exists, in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).  So you need to remove it.
3. Your lines `g++`, and `max=1` don't do anything.  Remove them.
4. Check whether `fopen` succeeded before operating on the file.
5. Check if the user passed a filename argument on the command line (ie: `argc >= 2` before attempting to reference `argv[1]`.
6. You compute the maximum length of all the words in your `maxChar` variable, but then you print 'nrChar` which is the length of the last word found.

This code compiles with no warnings using `gcc -Wall -Wextra` and gives the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    char *g,*p,linie[1000];
    int maxChar=0, nrChar=0;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    FILE *f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open %s for read!\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    g=fgets(linie,1000,f);
    while(g!=NULL)
    {
        p = strchr(linie, '\n');  //fgets leaves the '\n' in the buffer
        if (p != NULL) *p = 0;    //find the '\n' and replace with 0

        nrChar = strlen(linie);
        printf("%d\n", nrChar);   //need to print the value from strlen
        if(maxChar<nrChar)
        {
            maxChar = nrChar;
        }
        g=fgets(linie,1000,f);
    }
    printf("The longest word has %d letters \n",maxChar);

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i just realized i did some rookie mistakes, caused by the lack of knowledge in working in C. Your solution worked as expected and was pretty clear how it works. Thanks a mili!